# Accessing Redux State through this.props is throwing "Cannot read property name of undefined."

Tags: reactjs, redux

[Redux Dev Tools view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lf8F7.png)
Edit: Here is a picture of redux devtools. It is populating state with an array of objects. Anytime I try to access an object in the array I get this error [React Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FODPA.png)

I have a server that is getting data from yelp when it receives a get request and it sends the response from yelp up to the client.

When I try to access the server response that was called from the getFoodPlans() function, it shows up as state in the redux webtools but says "Cannot find property name of undefined", if you try to access it through props.

If I use an axios call to the endpoint and set local state with the response, I can access all the properties. I have a feeling that it has to do with the server, because if I send the whole businesses object from the server I get the same error with axios where I can't access a property of undefined.

Does this have to do with how I'm sending the data from the server to the client?

Thank you.

Server:

```
 router.get('/food', (req, res) => {
  const position = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15);
  axios
   .get(`${foodSearch}location=kansascity
         &&radius=${radius}&&cost=1,2,3&&categories=food`, {
         headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${apiKey}` }
    })
    .then(result => {
      res.json(result.data.businesses[position]);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
});
```

PlanActions.js:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { GET_FOOD_PLANS, PLAN_LOADING, GET_ERRORS, GET_ACTIVITY_PLANS } from 
'./types';

// Get Plans
export const getFoodPlans = () => dispatch => {
  dispatch(setPlanLoading());
  axios
    .get('/api/data/food')
    .then(res =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_FOOD_PLANS,
        payload: res.data
      })
    )
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_FOOD_PLANS,
        payload: err
      })
    );
};
```

planReducer.js:

```
import { GET_FOOD_PLANS, GET_ACTIVITY_PLANS, PLAN_LOADING } from 
'../actions/types';

const initalState = {
  food: {},
  activities: {},
  triggered: false,
  loading: false
};

export default function(state = initalState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case PLAN_LOADING:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true
      };
    case GET_FOOD_PLANS:
      return {
        ...state,
        food: action.payload,
        loading: false
      };
    case GET_ACTIVITY_PLANS:
      return {
        ...state,
        activities: action.payload,
        loading: false
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

PlanTomorrow.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { getFoodPlans } from '../../actions/planActions';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import axios from 'axios';

import ResultBox from '../Resultbox/ResultBox';

class PlanTomorrow extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      load: false,    
      activity1: {},
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.getFoodPlans();
    axios.get('/api/data/activity').then(res => this.setState({ activity1: 
    res.data }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="tomorrowform">
        <h2>Tomorrows Plan:</h2>
        <ul className="tomorrowform-data">
          <li id="item1">
            <ResultBox
              activity={this.props.plan.food.name}
              phone={this.props.plan.food.display_phone}
              rating={this.props.plan.food.rating}
            />
          </li>
          <li id="item2">
            <ResultBox
              activity={this.state.activity1.name}
              phone={this.state.activity1.display_phone}
              rating={this.state.activity1.rating}
            />
         </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

PlanTomorrow.propTypes = {
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  plan: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth,
  plan: state.plan
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { getFoodPlans }
)(PlanTomorrow);
```

Comment: In PlanTomorrow.js file, you are not mapping 'food' inside mapStateToProps function!

Comment: That is supposed to say this.props.plan.food. I fixed it in the code. Would that still matter?

Comment: Which line causes the error?

Comment: Where the ResultsBox component is getting passed activity={this.props.plan.food.name}. The data shows up in redux dev tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two points:

1. Do your API call from the componentDidMount(). It's the best for external API calls. Adviced by react docs.
2. You should call your action like `this.props.getFoodPlans()` as you pass it to your component via connect.
3. Because you are doing external call in the component your data won't be in the right shape on the first render. You should check that too.
   Add this before the return in your render method.

```js
const isFoodExists = !this.props.plan.food || !this.props.plan.food.length;

if (this.props.loading || !isFoodExists) {
  return null;
}
```

Here you should return the data for food as an array. And pass it as an array to your components.

Comment: I will try that. I copied an old version and it does call this.props.getFoodPlans(). The call is going through just fine and the redux dev tools shows the state being filled with the data.

Comment: You know what?=) Sorry, I was so curious about your case that I even found your project, run it, and even tried your question code of PlanTomorrow in it. It works, even if you call the function wrong. You plan reducer has a default state and it doesn't allow you to receive undefined for `food` or for even `plan`. Can't imagine what went wrong. Yeah, try it with your master branch.

Comment: The code on github is using axios calls instead of the redux action. It was the work around.

Comment: Yeah, I ment, I added action call and pros.

Comment: I am still having problems with it. When I send a single object from the server it works but if I send the business object, it populates an array with objects and I cant access anything within any of the objects in the array.

Comment: I have updated my answer because I got your problem. Data is not ready on the first render. You should check for it before use. I can give you my diff file with all the changes or show my git commit with example if you want.

Comment: So it works when the server is sending res.data.businesses[0], which is a single object, but when the server sends res.data.businesses, it doesn't work. I can't access any of the objects inside of the array that it sends. I've updated my code on github if you want to try it again.

Comment: I've sent you a PR.

Comment: It's works! I was reading about having two separate actions in your action file. One for making the call and then one for setting state. I wonder if that would also work. Thank you so much.